# how to enable leaflet edit & delete buttons in leaflet-draw-toolbar by default in vue2

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using leaflet map library. I am facing issue with leaflet-draw-toolbar in which I have edit & delete buttons but these buttons are disabled by default. please provide me solution by which I can enable these buttons & their click functionality by default. Thanks[This is my image in which edit & delete buttons are disabled by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VbkW.png)

```
  const drawOptions = {
    draw: {
      marker: false,
      polyline: false,
      polygon: {
        shapeOptions: {
          color: 'red',
          fillColor: 'red',
        },
      },
      rectangle: false,
      circle: false,
      circlemarker: false,
    },
    edit: {
      featureGroup: drawnItems,
      remove: true,
    },
    position: 'bottomleft',
  };
```

by default edit & delete buttons are disabled in leaflet-draw-toolbar. when i add shape by leaflet draw library (i am saving shapes in database) edit & delete buttons become enable & i am able to edit or delete shape but when i reload page i am getting shape from database & shape is rendering on map but edit & delete buttons become disable after reloading page. i want to get solution by which i can enable these buttons & their click functionalities

Comment: Please include the code used to initialize the leaflet toolbar.